# Problem with the rotation of the object

Tags: axis

The rotation of the object comes from the center of the axis, but not from the object itself.

How to make the rotation come from the object itself? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose *Transform Pivot Point > Median Point* for example, rather than *3D Cursor*:

[image]